# ColdFusion not maintaining session across cfhttp calls

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm having an issue trying to use `cfhttp`. I'm using an API that requires me to send login credentials, then send subsequent commands. The reply on the subsequent commands is "login required". After looking at my requests, I think I've found the issue but I don't understand it.

Here's my login call:

```
<cfhttp url="#Target#"  result="LoginAttempt"  method="POST" REDIRECT="No" useragent="#strUserAgent#"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="action" value="Login"  />
    <cfhttpparam name="loginUsername" value="#Username#" type="FORMFIELD" />    
    <cfhttpparam name="loginPassword" value="#Password#" type="FORMFIELD" /> 
</cfhttp>
```

When this returns `200 OK`, I set the cookie to use for future calls:

```
<cfset ThisCookie = LoginAttempt.responseHeader["Set-Cookie"] />
```

Then, proceeding with the next call:

```
<cfhttp url="#Target#"  result="CreateTransactionAttempt" method="POST" REDIRECT="No" useragent="#strUserAgent#"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Cookie" value="#ThisCookie#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="action" value="CreateTransaction" />
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="transactionName" value="#TransactionName#" />
</cfhttp>
```

The problem I think is this; when I look at the header of the second `cfhttp` call, it doesn't match the cookie provided by the first call. I'm not sure why this would be. On Ben Nadel's blog page [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/725-maintaining-sessions-across-multiple-coldfusion-cfhttp-requests.htm), he has a function that splits the returned cookie into a struct and passes that into the second call. I've tried that with the same result. Am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't match how? Could you post a santized example of what you're seeing versus what you expected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot take the `Set-Cookie` header from the response and just echo it as `Cookie` header in the request. [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) can contain directives like `Domain`, `Path`, `Secure`, `HttpOnly`, `Expires`, `Max-Age` etc. You need to strip them and reduce it to the cookie's key-value pair, because that's what the [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header in your request is supposed to contain.

## Example 1, single cookie

Response:

```
Set-Header: JSESSIONID=9335968036E8B5EE9F9D00032A5A665D; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

Key-Value-Pair:

```
Key: JSESSIONID
Val: 9335968036E8B5EE9F9D00032A5A665D
```

Request:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=9335968036E8B5EE9F9D00032A5A665D
```

## Example 2, multiple cookies

Response:

```
Set-Header: JSESSIONID=9335968036E8B5EE9F9D00032A5A665D; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Header: uid=d1b68f6fe0ca70e8d53bd3a2f32d06c1f1554317436; expires=Thu, 02-Apr-20 18:50:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.org; HttpOnly
```

Key-Value-Pairs:

```
Key: JSESSIONID
Val: 9335968036E8B5EE9F9D00032A5A665D

Key: uid
Val: d1b68f6fe0ca70e8d53bd3a2f32d06c1f1554317436
```

Request:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=9335968036E8B5EE9F9D00032A5A665D; uid=d1b68f6fe0ca70e8d53bd3a2f32d06c1f1554317436
```

---

For starters, something naive like:

```
<cfset ThisCookie = getToken(LoginAttempt.responseHeader["Set-Cookie"], 1, ";") />
```

could possibly already solve the problem for you.

Comment: getToken did indeed solve my problem.  The odd thing is the way I had it was working on the provider's test server but failed to work when I moved to production. I  think perhaps their test server was serving content over http so it worked by coincidence. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While researching this same problem I came across [CFHTTPSession.cfc by Ben Nadel](https://github.com/bennadel/CFHTTPSession.cfc) that deals with the cookies for you.